# ValueError The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing on django views

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

am Getting this error i cant figure a way to solve it here are the views.py

```
class SellerTransactionListView(ListView):
    model = Transaction
    template_name = "sellers/transaction_list_view.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        account = SellerAccount.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        if account.exists():
            products = Product.objects.filter(seller=account)
            return Transaction.objects.filter(product__in=products)
        return []
```

template transaction_list_view.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Transactions</h1>
<ul>

    {% include "sellers/transaction_list.html" with transaction_list=object_list %}

</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

and the transaction_list.html

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>Product</th>
<th>User</th>
<th>order_id</th>
<th>Sale Total</th>
    <th></th>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for trans in transaction_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ trans.product }}</td>
    <td>{{ trans.profile }}</td>
  <td>{{ trans.order_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ trans.amount }}</td>
    <td>{{ trans.timestamp|timesince }} ago</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

if i change the transaction_list_view.html the include part to

> {% include "sellers/transaction_list.html" with
>   transaction_list=transactions %}

the error disappears but the transactions are not showing.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: its simple account is queryset containting multiple results and you are trying to filter products with it which is not permitted either get single account or use IN

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `account`s is a `QuerySet`, that means that it is a collection that contains zero, one or more `SellerAccount`s, so you should use:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(seller__in=account)
```

so with the [**`__in`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in).

That being said, you can make the above query more effective by writing it as:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Transaction.objects.filter(product__seller__user=self.request.user)
```

Here you thus will return the `Transaction`s that have a `product` that have a `seller` that has as `user` the `self.request.user`.

Comment: How can I do this in a `get_or_create`? I am creating or getting a object that has a ManyToManyField. For example, `get_or_create(myMany2ManyField=manyQuerySets)`.

Comment: @AnonymousUser: you don't. This requires extra querying.